# Why am I getting ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column - when I'm not inserting?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is some SQL to set up with a very simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE CC_TEST2 
  ("CURRENCYID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAME" NVARCHAR2(255)) ;


insert into CC_TEST2 (select 1,'Testing issue'from dual);
commit;
```

Then this recreates the issue

```
    SELECT (step.Name ||
    'Commentary of 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890            1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890
    1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 12')
 as thing  FROM CC_TEST2 step
```

Any ideas?

I think it's something odd about nVarchar2? If I change the column type to varChar2 then it's OK. Sadly I can't change the column type of the actual production database where I'm getting the issue

Comment: maybe commit after insert?

Comment: Well clearly you are inserting - do you get the same from `INSERT INTO CC_TEST2 (1,'Testing Issue');`?

Comment: That's just setting up test data - the Select statement is where the error occurs

Comment: It's [easy to reproduce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10933/1).

Comment: Could you please post the result of `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';` ?

Comment: The result to the nls_database_parameters is - NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252, and 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "NAME" NVARCHAR2(255) is changed to "NAME" VARCHAR2(255) (i.e by using varchar2) you won't get any issue. You can test the same at 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cefd8/2

Comment: Changing from NVARCHAR2 to VARCHAR2 isn't an option, apparently.

Comment: okay then try "to_char(name) ||" It works,check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10933/12

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be a solution.

Comment: I hope there aren't special characters in your NVARCAR2 columns that don't pass a TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some strangeness with NVARCHAR2 and string concatenation.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/936c4/2

My understanding based on running the various statements in the SQL Fiddle is that the string constant on the right hand side of the concatenation operator || is also treated as an NVARCHAR2, and can be at most 1000 characters.

Comment: Can you please provide the link saying the maximum limit of NVARCHAR2? The maximum size of NVARCHAR2 or VARCHAR2 is 4000 byte. But, NVARCHAR2 always uses two byte character set (AL16UTF16 or UTF8). Maximum characters that can be stored in NVARCHAR2 datatype is 2000.

Comment: @tvm Yes, but when using a too-long string constant concatenated to an NVARCHAR2 column, you get ORA-01401, whereas you would expect ORA-01489 or some other error message.

Answer (score 0):

[As per oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i3253)

**NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 Datatypes**

`NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` are Unicode datatypes that store Unicode character data. They are also called as Native data types.

The `NVARCHAR2` datatype stores variable length character strings.

When you create a table with an `NVARCHAR2` column, the maximum size specified is always in character length semantics. Character length semantics is the default and only length semantics for `NVARCHAR2`.

For example, if national character set is `UTF8`, then the following statement defines the maximum byte length of 90 bytes:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NCHAR(30));
```

The maximum length of an `NVARCHAR2` column is 4000 bytes. It can hold up to 4000 characters. The actual data is subject to the maximum byte limit of 4000. The two size constraints must be satisfied simultaneously at run time.

It all depends on your character set and length semantics.

[**Reason for your problem is**](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:7143933880166)

> One other important thing to remember is that the upper bound of the
>   number of bytes stored in a VARCHAR2 is 4,000. However, even if you
>   specify VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), you may not be able to fit 4,000
>   characters into that field. In fact, you may be able to fit as few as
>   1,000 characters in that field if all of the characters take 4 bytes
>   to be represented in your chosen character set!

This holds good for Native datatype also.

**Solution:**

Use `CHAR` instead of `BYTES` as the length semantics for VARCHAR2 or CHAR.

> The reason is that a 20-character string in a single-byte character
>   set is 20 bytes long and will absolutely fit in a VARCHAR2(20).
>   However a 20-character field could be as long as 80 bytes in a
>   multibyte character set, and 20 Unicode characters may well not fit in
>   20 bytes.