# ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column when doing SELECT query containing LIKE

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I'm currently getting the below stack trace when trying to execute an SQL query using Java, Spring and Oracle's oci driver to connect a Rdb database. The column `ORGANIZATION_NAME` is defined in the database as `CHAR(26)`, the value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME` in the database is **Commercial Flooring Soluti** and the value I'm using for the `LIKE` clause is `%Commercial Flooring Solutitions%`. I've confirmed that the maximum value for the first parameter is 26 which is coming from the database. My question is does anybody know why this is happening for a `SELECT` statement? I would've expected the database/driver to truncate and handle this. Does it have something to do with the column type being `CHAR(26)`? It's unusual that the date columns are being set to 2000 (see trace log).

```
13:03:25,073 SEVERE [au.com.blah.http.logging.HttpLoggingFilter] (http- org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT
    header_record_uid,
    organization_name,
    organization_number
FROM
    direct_update_header@d
WHERE
    UPPER(organization_name) LIKE UPPER(?)
AND
    posting_date BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(?) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(?)
ORDER BY
    posting_date DESC
]; ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:82) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192) [spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
```

**Trace log:**

```
FROM
    direct_update_header@d
WHERE
    UPPER(organization_name) LIKE UPPER(:1 )
AND
    posting_date BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(:2 ) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:3 )
ORDER BY
    posting_date DESC
statement id: 036E70F0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.459::gta.gtachecksqlcode: Rdb returned SQLCODE: 0 for PREPARE
2015-08-13 13:50:50.459::gta.sequence_check: entry
2015-08-13 13:50:50.459::gta.sequence_check: exit status=0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.459::gta.gtapars: exit status=0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.459::*** GTAISDDL ***
2015-08-13 13:50:50.460::gtoosq.gtoosq: exit status=0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.460::gtoall.gtoopr: exit status = 0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.460::gtoall.gtopbnd: entry
2015-08-13 13:50:50.460::gtobr.gtobrp: entry
gtobr.gtobrp: BRPDEF:.....cursor : 1
gtobr.gtobrp:        ........pos : 1
gtobr.gtobrp:        .....oacdef : 7acb1818
gtobr.gtobrp:        .# oacdef's : 3
gtobr.gtobrp:        ........uac : 0
gtobr.gtobrp:        ...uac lnth : 0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.460::*** GTGBNDONE ***
2015-08-13 13:50:50.461::gta.gtadbnd: entry
statement id: 036E70F0
2015-08-13 13:50:50.461::gta.gtachecksqlcode: Rdb returned SQLCODE: 0 for DESCRIBE INPUT
gta.gtadbnd: SQLDA2 for (1): Describe Input
Cursor number 1, number of items 3
SQLVAR Item 0, Bindnam 1, Bindcol 1
type 449, octet_len 30, sqllen 26
data NULL
SQLVAR Item 1, Bindnam 2, Bindcol INSTR
type 449, octet_len 2004, sqllen 2000
data NULL
SQLVAR Item 2, Bindnam 3, Bindcol INSTR
type 449, octet_len 2004, sqllen 2000
data NULL
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228898/sql-error-ora-01401-inserted-value-too-large-for-column)

Comment: What are the datatype of columns? Please share schema details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seem to be possible for columns of type `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2` but not for `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2`

Refer [Why am I getting ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column - when I'm not inserting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537234/why-am-i-getting-ora-01401-inserted-value-too-large-for-column-when-im-not-i) where user faces a similar issue with `NVARCHAR2`

Looking at your query, you seem to be querying data via a DB Link (direct_update_header@d)

You can try using `CHAR` semantics in your database. It is strongly recommended when sharing data over database links. Refer [this page](http://abcdba.com/abcdbaservernlslengthsemantics)

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This best explains why I'm seeing this error. Rather than change the database, I've come up with a workaround which is a suitable quick solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### **UPDATE:**

I've come up with a workaround which is displayed in the below test. Rather than include the '%' for the `LIKE` clause as part of the parameter binding in the `MapSqlParameterSource`, I've moved it to the SQL itself.

```
public class JdbcNamedTemplate_Select_WithBindVariableWithoutLikeWildcard_ExecutesSuccessfully_IT extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

private String query;
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private MapSqlParameterSource params;
private List<Map<String, Object>> result;
private Exception exception;

@Override
public void given() {
    query = "SELECT * FROM direct_update_header@d WHERE UPPER(organization_name) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:organisationName) || '%' " +
            "AND posting_date BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(:fromDate) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:toDate)";
    jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("organisationName", String.format("%26s", "X"));
    params.addValue("fromDate", new Timestamp(DateUtils.now().toDate().getTime()));
    params.addValue("toDate", new Timestamp(DateUtils.now().toDate().getTime()));

}

@Override
public void when() {
    try {
        result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        exception = e;
    }
}

@Override
public void then() {
    assertNull(exception);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when running a SELECT on a view that contained a

```
cast(foo as VARCHAR2(20))
```

where the underlying type of `foo` was actually `NVARCHAR2(255)`. It was fixed by changing to

```
cast(foo as VARCHAR2(255 char))
```

However the error does not occur in a minimal example - the value is silently truncated instead. I haven't time now to narrow down further, but it may help other visitors to this question.